# How to create a Digg Reader link for my website?

Tags: rss, feed, digg

I am trying to add a Digg Reader link to my website and it's not working.

The link format is like this: http://digg.com/reader/feed/mywebsite/myfeed.rss

I can't find any documentation about this, is it not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the actual url you want to use is  `http://digg.com/reader/feed/http://mywebsite/myfeed.rss`
, but generally, rather than create links for every single reader, you should probably put a [SubToMe](https://www.subtome.com/#/) button, because it works with any reader, including Digg!

Comment: The link above to Digg Reader is actually not working, when linking to it, this is why I asked the question. I can't add the SubToMe button, I need to use custom links.

Comment: when you go to SubToMe website, click on Settings then subscribe button. you will see a pop up window. click on View full list of services button. you can then choose what service you want to connect or add url to, but most likely you need to sign in.